# What will be the proper assigning of variables (private and shared) in the parallelized do loop of the given subroutine GAUSSLEG?

Tags: openmp, private, shared, reduction

I am new about openmp. I am trying to parallelize do loop in subroutine GAUSSLEG. Variables Xg, Wg and Ng are taken from module matric. I am getting the unexpected results. I am confused about proper assigning of  variables(private and shared). Can somebody help me ?

```
SUBROUTINE GAUSSLEG(f,a,b,s)
     USE OMP_LIB
     USE MATRIC , ONLY : XG ,WG , NG
     IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION(A-H,O-Z)
     external f
     xm = 0.5d0*(b+a)
     xl = 0.5d0*(b-a)
     s = 0.d0
    !$omp parallel do reduction ( + : s) default(none)
    !$omp private(j) shared(xm,xl,wg,xg,ng,dx)

     do  j=1,ng
         dx = xl*xg(j)
         s = s + wg(j)*(func(xm+dx)+func(xm-dx))
     end do
   !$omp end parallel do

    s = xl*s/2.0
    return
  END
```

---

Hi, I have used the subroutine gaussleg to calculate the integration of sin(x) from 0 to pi, I get the same result (2.5464790894) whether i make dx private or shared but the exact result is 2.0.   I have also tried by putting xl*xg(j) directly and removing dx,  still getting same result as above.Without -openmp option in the compilation,  i get  the exact result 2.0.This is whole program.

```
  MODULE MATRIC
   IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER , PARAMETER :: NG = 40
    DOUBLE PRECISION , PARAMETER :: PI=2.0D0*ACOS(0.0D0)
    DOUBLE PRECISION ::  XG(60) , WG(60)
  END MODULE MATRIC
  program gauss
   use matric, only : xg,wg,pi
   implicit none
   double precision :: x1,x2,a,b,ans
   external :: f
   x1 = -1.0d0 ; x2 = 1.0d0
   a  = 0.0    ; b  = PI
   call gauleg(x1,x2)
   call gaussleg(f,a,b,ans)
   write(*,*)ans
  end program gauss
  !function to be integrated
  double precision function f(x)
        implicit none
        double precision, intent(in) :: x
        f = sin(x)
  end function f
  SUBROUTINE GAUSSLEG(func,a,b,ss)
     USE OMP_LIB
     USE MATRIC , ONLY : XG ,WG , NG
     double precision,intent(in) :: a , b
     double precision,intent(out)::ss
     double precision :: xm , xl , dx
     integer :: j
     double precision,external::func
     xm = 0.5d0*(b+a)
     xl = 0.5d0*(b-a)
     ss = 0.d0
    !$OMP PARALLEL DO REDUCTION( + : ss) default(none) &
    !$OMP PRIVATE(j,dx) SHARED(xm,xl,xg,wg)
       do  j=1,ng
           dx = xl*xg(j)
           ss = ss + wg(j)*(func(xm+dx)+func(xm-dx))
       end do
    !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
      ss = xl*ss/2.0
      return
      END
```

Comment: can you also provide an example of expected and actual output?

Comment: Hi sir,  i am sorry,  i made a mistake,  ng is not there in the shared list. With ng i was getting error so my shared list is (xm,xl,wg,xg,dx).  I tried to check subroutine by calculating the integration of sin(x) with x limit  0 to pi.  If i compile the program without  -openmp option, i get 2.00000 with is the exact answer

Answer (score 0):

Your code includes a canonical *data race*.  You have declared `dx` shared, then written

```
         dx = xl*xg(j)
```

so that all threads can update the same, shared, variable, without any co-ordination.  I think, but it is your responsibility to check this, that you can make `dx` private and have each thread look after its own value of the variable.

Incidentally.  DO NOT USE `implicit` typing, you're just asking for trouble.  Asking for trouble while you are trying to learn how to use OpenMP is just, well, asking for more trouble.  USE `implicit none`.  And don't respond *Oh, I'm just updating an existing codebase which uses implicit typing*.  If that's what you are doing, do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Got exact results in the following way.

SUBROUTINE QGAUSSP(func,a,b,ss)

```
     USE OMP_LIB
     USE MATRIC , ONLY : XG ,WG , NG
     implicit none
     double precision, intent(in) :: a , b
     double precision, intent(out):: ss
     double precision :: xm , xl , dx , xgd , wgd
     double precision :: s(NG)
     integer :: j,tid
     double precision,external::func
     xm = 0.5d0*(b+a)
     xl = 0.5d0*(b-a)
     ss = 0.d0
  !$omp parallel do private(j,xgd,wgd,dx) shared(xm,xl,xg,wg,s) num_threads(15) 
   do  j=1,ng
       xgd=xg(j)
       wgd=wg(j)
       dx = xl*xgd
       s(j)=wgd*(func(xm+dx)+func(xm-dx))
   end do
  !$omp end parallel do
   ss=sum(s) *xl/2.0
   return
  END
```